# Android database issue

Tags: android, database

The emulator can access the database but doesn't work on the android devices.
The android devices will close this application automatically when I open.
I am using the Google APIs (Google Inc.) - API Level 10 emulator
    package ict.mobile;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DatabaseMemberQuery extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    SQLiteDatabase db;
String sql;
Cursor cursor = null;
String[] columns = { "mid", "name", "password", "age" };
TextView tvData;
String dataStrHeader = String.format("%4s %-12s %-9s %3s\n", "Mid", "Name", "Password", "Age");
String dataStr;
Button btnDBinitial, btnAction;

public void findView() {
    tvData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.data);
    btnDBinitial = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDBinitial);
    btnAction = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAction);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    findView();
    btnDBinitial.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnAction.setOnClickListener(this);
    initialDB();
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.equals(btnDBinitial)) {
        initialDB();
    }
    else if (v.equals(btnAction)) {
        try {
            db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/ict.mobile/MemberDB", null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);


            cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from Member where age >=30 order by mid", null);
            int result = cursor.getCount();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Count: " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            dataStr = dataStrHeader;
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                int mid = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("mid"));
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
                String password = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("password"));
                int age = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("age"));
                dataStr += String.format("%4d %-12s %-9s %3d\n", mid, name, password, age);

            }
            tvData.setText(dataStr);
            db.close();
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

public void initialDB() {
    try {

        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/ict.mobile/MemberDB", null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
        sql = "DROP TABLE if exists Member;";
        db.execSQL(sql);

        sql= "CREATE TABLE Member(" + "mid int PRIMARY KEY ," + "name text, "
                + "password text, "+ "age int); ";

        db.execSQL(sql);

        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Member(mid, name, password, age) values"
                + "(1001, 'Amy Carl', '12345', 16); ");

        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Member(mid, name, password, age) values"
                + "(1002, 'Helen Leung', '88888', 25); ");

        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Member(mid, name, password, age) values"
                + "(1003, 'Robert Chan', 'iloveu', 61); ");

        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Member(mid, name, password, age) values"
                + "(1004, 'Carol Wong', 'peterpan', 33); ");

        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Member(mid, name, password, age) values"
                + "(1005, 'Carman Wong', 'pooh', 44); ");

        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Member(mid, name, password, age) values"
                + "(1006, 'John Chan', 'johnchan', 28); ");

        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Member(mid, name, password, age) values"
                + "(1007, 'Paul Lam', 'apple', 16); ");

        cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from Member order by mid", null);

        dataStr = dataStrHeader;
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int mid = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("mid"));
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
            String password = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("password"));
            int age = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("age"));
            dataStr += String.format("%4d %-12s %-9s %3d\n", mid, name, password, age);
        }
        tvData.setText(dataStr);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Table Member is created and initialised.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        db.close();
    }
    catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Show the output of logcat: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

Answer (score 0):

The path of your databases should be

`/data/data/ict.mobile/databases/MemberDB`

[According to docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#sqlite)

> To use sqlite3, enter a remote shell on the emulator instance, as described above, then invoke the tool using the sqlite3 command. Optionally, when invoking sqlite3 you can specify the full path to the database you want to explore. Emulator/device instances store SQLite3 databases in the folder **/data/data/< package_name >/databases/**.

Here's an example:

```
adb -s emulator-5554 shell
# sqlite3 /data/data/com.example.google.rss.rssexample/databases/rssitems.db`
```

Before you execute the app with the new path delete your app from the emulator/device.